# UITextField: textFieldShouldBeginEditing fires, but keyboard does not show

Tags: ios6, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate

I have a text field that is apparently successfully calling delegate methods as the following method fires when I tap on the test field, but no keyboard shows.

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    NSLog(@"should begin editing");

    return YES;
}
```

Any ideas as to why?

**A couple of details:** This text field happens to be in a view controller in a storyboard. The first time I segue to this view the text field works fine. The subsequent times I segue to this view it does not work. I imagine this is a big clue to why I am getting the described behavior, but I have not been able to figure it out yet.

Comment: Another clue is that if I return the text field (textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField) and resign first responder, before I leave the view, everything works as expected. I set up the segue myself, without a navigation controller, so maybe I missed something important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the issue by adding the code below to the prepareForSegue: method. Seems to work.

```
if (_textField.isFirstResponder) {
    [_textTextField resignFirstResponder];
}
```